# Creating an appropriate colorscale for choropleth in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, colorbar, choropleth

I am attempting to replicate the colorscale in this map: https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/pewez6/oc_us_counties_by_population_density/

I am essentially trying to show variation in color for counties that record population densities under the thousand mark (these counties are washed out by the outliers). I have played around with the `range_color` argument in `px.choropleth` and have attempted to create my own colorscales but cannot seem to replicate the colorscale present in the map in the link. I was hoping https://react-colorscales.getforge.io/ might help me but I have not figured it out yet.

I have not been able to understand exactly how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my best attempt. I am looking for a more gradual gradient for the lower values. [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share in the question what you have tried so far? You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) very helpful in understanding how to ask a good question on this site.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/ the first example?

Comment: @Hazmah I did look at the documentation there but the first example uses data that has a range of 1-20, my data ranges from 1-20,000 with the majority of observations in the 0-500 range. I updated the OP to include the best scale I have thus far.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can consider is clipping the highest and lowest values.  The true values can still be shown in the hover information.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import tempfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pathlib import Path
import io
import plotly.express as px

# get country population data
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    
    with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(requests.get("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/EN.POP.DNST?downloadformat=csv").content)) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall(d)
    df = pd.read_csv(list(Path(d).glob("API_*.*"))[0], skiprows=3)
    
df = df.loc[:,["Country Name", "Country Code","2020"]].dropna()

# clip population density to stop large and small values running away with cmap
df["Density"] = df["2020"].clip(lower=df["2020"].quantile(.1), upper=df["2020"].quantile(.80))

px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="Country Code",
    color="Density",  
    hover_name="Country Name", 
    hover_data={"2020":":.2f", "Density":":.2f"},
    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Oranges,
)
```

[image]

### logarithmic color scale

- another option is to use a logarithmic color scale
- have also made this color scale discrete.  This is not so necessary, change to `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Oranges` to use true continuous scale

```
colors = px.colors.sequential.Oranges

df["Density"] = np.log1p(df["2020"])
edges = pd.cut(df["Density"], bins=len(colors)-1, retbins=True)[1]
edges = edges[:-1] / edges[-1]
# color scales don't like negative edges...
edges = np.maximum(edges, np.full(len(edges), 0))

cc_scale = (
    [(0, colors[0])]
    + [(e, colors[(i + 1) // 2]) for i, e in enumerate(np.repeat(edges, 2))]
    + [(1, colors[-1])]
)

ticks = np.linspace(df["Density"].min(), df["Density"].max(), len(colors))[1:-1]

px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="Country Code",
    color="Density",  
    hover_name="Country Name", 
    hover_data={"2020":":.2f", "Density":":.2f"},
    color_continuous_scale=cc_scale
).update_layout(
    coloraxis={
        "colorbar": {
            "tickmode": "array",
            "tickvals": ticks,
            "ticktext": np.expm1(ticks).round(0),
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I did not know about clipping, I am checking that out now. I guess I would want values from 0-100 to remain as is, then clip values above that in some fashion. Exploring this now.

Comment: carried on exploring after posting this answer, another option is use a logarithmic scale